# How to make Monday start day in DatePicker Calendar Java - JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, datepicker, scenebuilder, java-calendar

I'm working on an application and using JavaFX. I am using the built-in `DatePicker` but the calendar starts from Sunday, as visible on the image below. How to make the calendar start on Monday?

[image]

Comment: Note that if you're running this on a JVM where the default locale is one in which the standard is for Monday to be the first day of the week, this will happen automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this:

```
@FXML 
private DatePicker date;

//In the initialize method you can use the following code:

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    date.setOnShowing(e -> Locale.setDefault(Locale.Category.FORMAT, Locale.UK));
    //...
}
```